# Doc comment for parameter $parameters does not match | | actual variable name $resource

Tags: php, symfony

I have this error when i try commit to push my work .. I write parameters in comments annotation ... in codfe i write multiple function content parameters and resources and also options and all type this parameters is array and also content type parameters int

[image]

code handler:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Handler;

use AppBundle\Entity\University;
use AppBundle\Form\UniversityType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\formFactory;

/**
 * UniversityHandler.
 */
class UniversityHandler implements HandlerInterface
{
    /**
     *function construct.
     *
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     * @param formFactory            $formFactory
     * @param RequestStack           $requestStack
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, formFactory $formFactory, RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    /**
     *function get.
     *
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function get($id)
    {
        throw new \DomainException('Method UniversitaireHandler::get not implemented');
    }

    /**
     *function all.
     *
     * @param int $limit
     * @param int $offset
     */
    public function all($limit = 10, $offset = 0)
    {
        throw new \DomainException('Method UniversitaireHandler::all not implemented');
    }

    /**
     *function post.
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @param array $options
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    public function post(array $parameters, array $options = [])
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $form = $this->formFactory->create(UniversityType::class, new University(), array('csrf_protection' => 'false'));
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()) {
            $universitaire = $form->getData();
            $this->persistAndFlush($universitaire);

            return $universitaire;
        }

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     *function put.
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @param array $options
     * @param array $resource
     */
    public function put($resource, array $parameters, array $options)
    {
        throw new \DomainException('Method UniversitaireHandler::put not implemented');
    }

    /**
     *function patch.
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @param array $options
     * @param array $resource
     */
    public function patch($resource, array $parameters, array $options)
    {
        throw new \DomainException('Method UniversitaireHandler::patch not implemented');
    }

    /**
     *function delete.
     *
     * @param array $resource
     */
    public function delete($resource)
    {
        throw new \DomainException('Method UniversitaireHandler::delete not implemented');
    }

    /**
     *function persisteAndFlush.
     */
    protected function persistAndFlush($object)
    {
        $this->em->persist($object);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

how to resolve this error please ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing a PHP Code Sniffer error that is giving you errors for violating your organization's code style guidelines. [Here's the rule](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/b95ff2c3b122a3ee4b57d149a57d2afce65522c3/src/Standards/PEAR/Sniffs/Commenting/FunctionCommentSniff.php#L349) that your code is failing against.

Essentially, it wants you to rearrange your PHPDoc comments to align with the parameters in your method signatures:

```
/**
 * function put.
 *
 * @param array $parameters
 * @param array $options
 * @param array $resource
 */
public function put($resource, array $parameters, array $options)
```

should be rearranged to be:

```
/**
 * function put.
 *
 * @param array $resource
 * @param array $parameters
 * @param array $options
 */
public function put($resource, array $parameters, array $options)
```